# HPA increases the number of replicas higher than expected

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks, hpa

I have added a memory utilization based HPA for one of the deployments on my AKS cluster and am observing a strange behavior with HPA maintaining a number of replicas higher than expected.

```
Name:                                                     [REDACTED]
Namespace:                                                default
Labels:                                                   app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm
Annotations:                                              meta.helm.sh/release-name: [REDACTED]
                                                          meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: default
CreationTimestamp:                                        Thu, 13 Apr 2023 12:15:59 -0700
Reference:                                                Deployment/[REDACTED]
Metrics:                                                  ( current / target )
  resource memory on pods  (as a percentage of request):  229% (197150264888m) / 540%
Min replicas:                                             16
Max replicas:                                             64
Deployment pods:                                          46 current / 46 desired
Conditions:
  Type            Status  Reason              Message
  ----            ------  ------              -------
  AbleToScale     True    ReadyForNewScale    recommended size matches current size
  ScalingActive   True    ValidMetricFound    the HPA was able to successfully calculate a replica count from memory resource utilization (percentage of request)
  ScalingLimited  False   DesiredWithinRange  the desired count is within the acceptable range
Events:           <none>
```

Having really hard time understanding the logic behind HPA's decisions to increase the number of replicas from original 16 to 46. The memory request for target deployment is 84Mi. The target average memory utilization is defined as 540%. And as it can be seen from the HPA resource description above the memory average utilization is at 229%. According to HPA scaling [formula](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/#algorithm-details) it should have decreased the number of replicas to 20 (or should have not increased to 46 in the first place).

> desiredReplicas = ceil(46 * 229/540) = 20

Any insights as to why HPA would increase and keep the number of replicas at 46 ?